# Как сделать перенаправление домена через DNS?

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен, поддомены

Есть субдомен http://gamer-by-life.mega-mind.info/ где хранится сайт. Также есть домен http://gamer-by-life.com/. Как сделать так, что бы домен http://gamer-by-life.com/ открывал сайт того субдомена, не перенаправлял на тот сайт, а именно открывал его в своем домене? Оба домена мои.

Другими словами - как сделать парковочный домен для субдомена?

Answer (score 2):

Для этой цели необходимо использовать **CNAME** запись.

Answer (score 1):

У регистратора домена `gamer-by-life.com`.

1 Удаляете все `A`, `AAAA` и `CNAME` записи на `@` и `www`.

2 Создаёте `CNAME` запись для @ и www. (точка на конце домена обязательна)

```
@ 14400 CNAME gamer-by-life.mega-mind.info. 
www 14400 CNAME gamer-by-life.mega-mind.info.
```

3 Сохраняете и ждёте.

Comment: что означает «14400»?

Comment: TTL, у некоторых регистраторов он может явно не указываться. TTL указывает время жизни записи, в секундах, т.е. время на которое его будут кешировать, другие не авторитетные NS-сервера.

Answer (score 0):

1. в настройках сервера `http://gamer-by-life.mega-mind.info/` добавить запись, что у этого сервера может быть запрошен рессурс по url `http://gamer-by-life.com/` (зависит от типа сервера/хостинга)
2. в настройках DNS'a который "разруливает" `http://gamer-by-life.com/`, добавить запись типа `A`, указав целевой хост `gamer-by-life.mega-mind.info`